# Using EclipseLink JPA to store XML type to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to JPA, and I have a question on how to use JPA to store XML type to PostgreSQL.  I am simply expanding an existing POJO to include persisting an additional XML field to a column.  The POJO looks something like this (I purposely left out a bunch of other columns to make this shorter, before adding this additional XML type, this POJO can persist into PostgreSQL just fine via JPA).

```
public class Finding implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5814053129578212916L;
    ...
    @Column(name = "PLUGIN_TEXT_XML")
    private String pluginTextXML;

    public void setPluginText(String pluginText) {
        this.pluginText = pluginText;
    }
    public String getPluginTextXML() {
            return pluginTextXML;
    }
}
```

When I try to persist this POJO, I received a PSQLException

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "plugin_text_xml" is of type xml but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 668
```

I have been trying to look online on how to map a XML type in JPA but no luck.  If anyone can give me a hand or point me to a site online so I can read up more on it then it would be a great help!  Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL is annoyingly strict about implicit casts between text-like types like `json`, `xml`, etc.

The strictly correct solution is to use `setObject(the_string, java.sql.Types.SQLXML)` when setting the parameter with JDBC. This is difficult through ORM layers, and many ORMs don't seem to understand the SQL/XML types directly.

You can tell PostgreSQL to permit the cast from `text` to `xml` to be made implicitly by modifying the system catalogs. It isn't ideal, but it'll work.

In `psql`, you can use `\dC xml` to list cats to `xml`:

```
                               List of casts
    Source type    |    Target type    |      Function      |   Implicit?   
-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------
 character         | xml               | xml                | no
 character varying | xml               | xml                | no
 text              | xml               | xml                | no
 xml               | character         | (binary coercible) | in assignment
 xml               | character varying | (binary coercible) | in assignment
 xml               | text              | (binary coercible) | in assignment
(6 rows)
```

See the "implicit: no" ?

You need to make them assignment-convertable. Since they're built-in types you can't `CREATE CAST` for them, you have to update the catalogs directly, changing the `pg_cast` table.

```
UPDATE pg_cast SET castcontext = 'a' 
FROM pg_cast c 
INNER JOIN pg_type srctype ON (c.castsource = srctype.oid)
INNER JOIN pg_type dsttype on (c.casttarget = dsttype.oid) 
WHERE pg_cast.oid = c.oid 
  AND srctype.typname IN ('text','varchar') 
  AND dsttype.typname = 'xml';
```

Messing with the system catalogs can have unexpected effects. In this case I believe it is fairly safe to make this change, but it's still messing with the system's innards. Proceed at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use a Converter to convert between String and Postgres XML type.

Otherwise, you can extend your PostgreSQLPlatform to support the type. (see, DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(), DatabasePlatform.getCustomModifyValueForCall() and DatabasePlatform.shouldUseCustomModifyForCall()).

I would suggest you also log a bug if you can't get it to work.  There should be an easy way to do this.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply.  Is this the converter method that you were referring to?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961237/mapping-oracle-xmltype-on-jpa-eclipselink   I just tried it and still getting the same exception.

Comment: Actually you can use JPA converter to PGobject of Postgres JDBC
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26126168/1535995