# Java type in JDBC to Postgres ltree

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement, ltree

Does anyone know what Java type maps to a Postgres ltree type?

I create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (text name, path ltree);
```

A couple of inserts:

```
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Alice', 'ROOT.first.parent');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Bob', 'ROOT.second.parent');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Ted', 'ROOT.first.parent.child');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Carol', 'ROOT.second.parent.child');
```

Nothing strange there. Now I want to batch this up using a PreparedStatment:

```
public final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO foo( name, path) VALUES (?, ?)";

public void insertFoos(final List<Foo> foos)
{
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().batchUpdate(INSERT_SQL, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter()
{
  @Override
  public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException
  {
    ps.setString(1, foos.get(i).getName());
    ps.setString(2, foos.get(i).getPath());
  }

  @Override
  public int getBatchSize()
  {
    return foos.size();
  }
});
```

}

This generates the following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO foo( name, path) VALUES (?, ?)]; nested exception is
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "path" is of type ltree but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Clearly I'm missing something. Why is it that I can insert 'something' using pure SQL but not JDBC?

Comment: You can do it from plain SQL not JDBC because in plain SQL your literal is treated as `unknown`-typed. Try `INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Alice', 'ROOT.first.parent'::text);` or `PREPARE x(text, text) AS INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ($1,$2)` to see the equivalent from psql.

Comment: And this question shows you the UserType you may need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287897/getting-error-when-mapping-postgresql-ltree-column-in-hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create stored procedure and call it from CallableStatement with String param to insert row with ltree via it, if preparedStatemnt.setString() isn't working?

Other solution may be `ps.setObject(2, foos.get(i).getPath(), Types.OTHER);`, but I can't check it now.

Comment: `ps.setObject(2, foos.get(i).getPath(), Types.OTHER);` did the trick!

Comment: This answer should really be two: I voted +1, but I voted +1 for the `setObject()` solution, not the stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

This is yet another variant of the strict casting issues in PostgreSQL interacting with client drivers and ORMs that send everything they don't understand as String.

You need to use `setObject` with `Types.OTHER`, IIRC.

```
    ps.setObject(2, foos.get(i).getName(), Types.OTHER);
```

which PgJDBC should send as a bind param of type `unknown`. Because you're working with PgJDBC directly this is easy for you to deal with, luckily; it's a real pain when people are using ORM layers.

See:

- [Macaddr/Inet type of postgres in slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285414/macaddr-inet-type-of-postgres-in-slick/21299240?noredirect=1#comment32306997_21299240)
- [Mapping postgreSQL JSON column to Hibernate value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15974474/398670)
- http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACTajFZ8+hg_kom6QiVBa94Kx9L3XUqZ99RdUsHBFkSb1MoCPQ@mail.gmail.com

for background.

Comment: Are there any indirect implications of sending a bind param of type unknown?

Comment: @mFeinstein it can affect overload resolution causing an error if there are multiple candidates for a function .

Comment: Ok, in my case I am seding an `inet` type