# Spring JPA with Postgres ltree extension

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, ltree

I am trying to make ltree indexing work with Spring JPA. I have an entity that contains the path like this

```
@Type(type = "com.thomaster.ourcloud.model.filesystem.LTreeType")
@Column(columnDefinition="ltree")
private String relativePath;
```

The LTreeType class is a copy paste from here [Getting error when mapping PostgreSQL LTREE column in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287897/getting-error-when-mapping-postgresql-ltree-column-in-hibernate).

The index is properly done in the database, the ltree extension is added. Still when I run the following query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE relative_path ~ lquery(:pathToSearch)", nativeQuery = true)
List<FileSystemElement> findAllByPath(@Param("pathToSearch") String pathToSearch);
```

I get
`org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`.

When I change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE relative_path ~ CAST(:pathToSearch AS lquery)
#OR TO THIS
SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE relative_path @> CAST(:pathToSearch AS ltree)
#OR TO THIS
SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE relative_path @> ltree(:pathToSearch)
#OR TO THIS
SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE ltree(relative_path) ~ lquery(:pathToSearch)
```

I get the same error.

For

```
SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE relative_path @> lquery(:pathToSearch)
```

I get

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: ltree @> lquery
```

And for:

```
SELECT * FROM file_system_element WHERE ltree(relative_path) ~ ltree(:pathToSearch)
```

I get:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: ltree ~ ltree
```

As you can see, I tried almost every combination, and still no result. I also tried the same queries as native queries on the entity manager, but it makes no difference. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was my mistake. The query parameter was

`"folder.anotherFolder"`

instead of

`"folder.anotherFolder.*"`