# How can one get Hibernate to use UserType for hbm2java code generation?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-tools, hbm2java

My situation is that I have a Spring Boot application, a PostgreSQL database, and use the hbm2java hibernate Maven plugin to generate the entity classes. The database uses types for which JPA/Hibernate do not have a matching builtin type (example: ltree), so my idea is to use a UserType.

I have created an LTreeType.java class implementing the UserType interface. How can I get hbm2java to use it for every database column of type ltree?

EDIT:

I found out so far that I have to either create a reveng.xml file or subclass `DefaultReverseEngineeringStrategy`. I have no idea how to tell the plugin to use the former (if it even still exists - this whole mess is completely undocumented), or how to actually get my subclass to work with the Maven plugin.

For the former, `<revengFile>` does seem to work, although I do end up with the error `Execution entity-generation of goal org.hibernate.tool:hibernate-tools-maven:6.2.1.Final:hbm2java failed: Could not resolve named type`.

So if anyone knows how to tell either Maven or this darned plugin to add my normal source folder to the classpath, this might potentially solve the problem.

As a final word of advice: stay away as far as possible from hibernate-tools if you have the choice. It's an undocumented mess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error when mapping PostgreSQL LTREE column in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287897/getting-error-when-mapping-postgresql-ltree-column-in-hibernate)

Comment: No, because it does not tell me how I can configure hbm2java to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally managed to do it. It's complicated, to say the least.

First, you have to create your user type - make sure to implement both `UserType<>` and `JdbcType` - in this case, I used `UserType<LTree>` and created an `LTree` class to hold the value, but you could also just use `String`.

Then you need to subclass `DelegatingStrategy` as well as whatever SQLDialect you are using - in my example, it's `PostgreSQLDialect`.

ExampleReverseEngineeringStrategy:

```java
public class ExampleReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingStrategy {
  public ExampleReverseEngineeringStrategy(RevengStrategy delegate) {
    super(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  public String columnToHibernateTypeName(TableIdentifier table, String columnName, int sqlType, int length, int precision, int scale, boolean nullable, boolean generatedIdentifier) {
    if(columnName.equals("path")) {
      return "ltree";
    } else {
      return super.columnToHibernateTypeName(table, columnName, sqlType, length, precision, scale, nullable, generatedIdentifier);
  }
}
```

ExamplePostgreSQLDialect:

```java
public class ExamplePostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {
  @Override
  public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
    typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().register(LTreeType.INSTANCE, "ltree");
  }
}
```

Finally, I used the Maven antrun plugin. This is by far the longest code block, so beware:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-ant</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>entity-generation-ant</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <echo message="Ant: Running Hibernatetool with ${project.build.sourceDirectory}" />
                <property name="maven_compile_classpath"
                refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                <property name="maven_test_classpath"
                refid="maven.test.classpath" />
                <path id="hibernatetool.path">
                  <pathelement path="${maven_compile_classpath}" />
                  <pathelement path="${maven_test_classpath}" />
                  <pathelement path="${project.build.sourceDirectory}" />
                  <pathelement path="${project.build.outputDirectory}" />
                </path>
                <taskdef name="hibernatetool"
                classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
                classpathref="hibernatetool.path" />
                <hibernatetool destdir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources">

                  <classpath>
                    <path refid="hibernatetool.path" />
                    <path location="${project.build.outputDirectory}" />
                  </classpath>
                  <jdbcconfiguration propertyfile="src/main/resources/application.properties"
                  packagename="com.example.db"
                  reversestrategy="com.example.SparsanaReverseEngineeringStrategy">

                    <!-- revengfile="src/main/resources/hibernate.reveng.xml" > -->
                    <fileset dir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}" />
                  </jdbcconfiguration>
                  <hbm2java jdk5="true" ejb3="true" />
                </hibernatetool>
              </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

It might also work with the "normal" hbm2java Maven plugin, I didn't test that yet, I didn't have the nerve yet. Hopefully this will help someone in as dire a situation as I was.