# Using Websphere Liberty JPA (EclipseLink) to Store XML DB2 data type

Tags: xml, jpa, db2, eclipselink, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to save and retrieve a database row using JPA in Websphere Liberty.
Database engine is DB2, the table has a XML data type column, and this column is mapped as a String in JPA. 
This worked well using OpenJpa, but moving to EclipseLink causes a null String to be retrieved. Note that the save operation works well, problem only exists during read operation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DATASET")
@NamedQueries( {
@NamedQuery(name = "DataSet.findByNameId", query = "SELECT ds FROM DataSet AS ds WHERE ds.name = :name")
 })
public class DataSet implements Serializable {
 ...
  @Column(name="DATASETDEF", unique=false, nullable=true)
  private String datasetDef;

 public static DataSet findByName(EntityManager em, String datasetName) {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("DataSet.findByNameId");
    q.setParameter("name", datasetName);
    DataSet dataset = (DataSet)q.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("-->" + dataset.getDatasetDef()); // <-- THIS IS NULL
    return dataset;
 }
```

I activated EclipseLink logs, and the query is executed correctly, including the XML field:

```
eclipselink I CWWJP9990I: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.WAS-  v20160817-8475a53
eclipselink.sql 3 SELECT DATASETID, DATASETDEF, DESCRIPTION, NAME, UPDATEFREQUENCY FROM UCC.DATASET WHERE (NAME = ?)
bind => [VEHICLE]
SystemOut  O -->null
```

I see similar problems also occur using Postgresql:
[Using EclipseLink JPA to store XML type to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310219/using-eclipselink-jpa-to-store-xml-type-to-postgresql) or using Oracle: [Mapping Oracle XMLType on JPA (EclipseLink)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961237/mapping-oracle-xmltype-on-jpa-eclipselink/3977280#3977280) 
Which is the correct way to handle this problem?

Comment: Is name the ID?  If not, try Em.refresh() to force the object to be reloaded, to verify that this doesn't have something to do with differences in the cache.

Comment: Hi Chris. the Name is a unique index, not an id. The problem persists even restarting the server, and doing it as the very first operation, so the cache is not impacted in this case. However, I just tried it and it doesn't work. Refreshing is done, internal query is by PK, but result is the same.